# Finding audio signal FFT distinct peaks

Tags: python, audio, signals, fft

[FFT result graph with peaks marked on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZSar.png)

I am trying to get the distinct peaks but haven't been able to. I got the highest peak and tried to break down the x-axis into chunks but that approach did not work either. One of the distinct peaks was skipped. Also, scanning the x-axis chunks was not reliable from one signal to another.

```py
def sound_fft(sound, rate):
    n = len(sound)  #How long is the file
    T = 1/rate      #Sampling interval in time

    yf = scipy.fft.fft(sound)   # Do FFT
    yf = abs(yf)    #Get rid of the imaginary part

    peaks,_ = find_peaks(yf, height=10) #Find the peaks (peaks > 10)

    peak1 = np.argmax(yf)
    print("Max peak at freq: ", peak1)

    xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), int(n/2))
    #xf = np.linspace(0.0, T*rate, int(n/2))
    one_side = np.abs(yf[:n//2])
    #print(one_side)

    #plt.plot(one_side) #plot one side of the FFT

    plt.plot(one_side)
    plt.plot(peaks, yf[peaks], "x")
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlabel("Frequency")
    plt.ylabel("Magnitude")
    plt.show()

    #return plt.show()

def main():
    file_path = "dn2.wav"
    samples, sampling_rate = librosa.load(file_path, sr = None, mono = True, 
    offset = 0.0, duration = None)
    sound_fft(samples, sampling_rate)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This code is really hard to read. Your variable names are completely unhelpful. There's LOADS of areas where the code can be pared down/factorized. Use `numpy` for everything; your use of `numpy` is inconsistent and it both makes things harder to follow *and* makes your code less efficient. I'd strongly recommend factoring out your peak finding code since you're just repeating the exact same 5-6 lines of code over and over. I also can't see where `k` is defined other than in a `for` loop, but you seem to be using it everywhere in your code as an index value. Also it's spelled "length".

Comment: I will break things up into different modules after I figure out the peak part; that's a no brainer. No one asked for spelling correction.

Comment: _I got the highest peak and tried to break down the x-axis into chunks but that approach did not work either. One of the distinct peaks was skipped. Also, it is not reliable from one signal to another._ you should post your solution to this. Finding peaks is just a case of finding maximum abs values in your Fourier transform.

Comment: @navid you're a lot less likely to get help when your code is as awful to read as what you have posted. I'm being serious. I took about 5 minutes looking at your code before deciding it was a waste of my time. Improve your code quality. Not only will others be more likely to help, but you may find issues with your implementation in the process. For instance, it's still not clear what you're trying to do with `g[k] = yf[0]` when `k` is not given a value anywhere except in a `for` loop earlier.

Comment: @blorgon I edited the code. It should be simple and easy to follow. g[k] = yf[0], helped to get the comparison started. I stored the 1st value of yf in it and then started comparing it with the rest...with np.argmax() I got the highest peak but need to get the other two distinct peaks. If you check the graph, I have peaks at ~393 (this is the highest argmax got this), ~226 and ~661.

Comment: It's not really clear what your issue is. What output are you expecting? Where is the `find_peaks()` function defined?

Comment: @blorgon I need the top three or four distinct peaks. So far, I was able to get one of the distinct peaks by using np.argmax(). find_peaks is coming from scipy.signal library. "from scipy.signal import find_peaks"

Comment: How are you defining "distinct"? Can you not just take the first three or four elements from `sorted(yf)`? The `scipy.signal.find_peaks` has a property called `peak_prominences`, perhaps you can start there. Look into the documentation.

Comment: @blorgon Distinc could be some type of local maxima. At the distinct peak, we have several neighboring smaller peaks to the left and right that we need to ignore and then move to the next distinct peak and do the same. I believe I looked into the prominences but will check it out again